# Changing nonzeros in certain columns of a sparse matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in MATLAB:

```
N=1000;
P=0.01;
A=sprand(N,N,P);
```

and I want to change all non zero entries at certain columns into ones.

That is, something like this:

```
c=randi(N,[1,round(N/10)]);
A(non zeros at columns c)=1;
```

Of course it can be done in a for loop, but that's clearly not the solution I'm looking for.
I tried several solutions using nnz, nonzeros, spfun - but with no soccess.
Can anyone come up with a simple way to do it?

Thanks,
Elad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
A(:,c) = abs(sign(A(:,c))); % take the absolute value of the sign for all entries 
                            % in the submatrix defined by the columns in c, and 
                            % then assign the result back
```

Equivalently,

```
A(:,c) = logical(A(:,c);
```

or

```
A(:,c) = A(:,c)~=0;
```

These may not be fast, because they process all entries in those columns, not just the nonzero entries. [Dohyun's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672811/2586922) is probably faster.

Comment: Luis' solution solves the problem. I thought it can be further improved by using spfun, to avoid processing all entries in columns c but it turn out wrong:
* the abs was removed since my entries are always positive

N = 1000000;
P = 20/N;
A = sprand(N,N,P);
c = randi(N,[1,N/10]);

tic
A(:,c) = sign(A(:,c));
toc
0.263002 seconds.

tic
A(:,c) = spfun(@sign,A(:,c));
toc
0.310704 seconds.
The time difference may not seem substantial, but it's consistent over trials. Considering the small fraction of zeros in columns c (20/1e6) it is intriguing that spfun is not much faster.

Comment: @user2179331 Other possibilities are `A(:,c) = logical(A(:,c))`  or `A(:,c) = A(:,c)~=0`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
N = 1000;
P = 0.01;
A = sprand(N,N,P);

c = unique(randi(N,[1,round(N/10)]))'; % sorted column index
[r,cind] = find(A(:,c));

A(sub2ind([N,N],r,c(cind)))=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to [Luis Mendos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39673727/3635260), but a bit simpler

```
A(:,c) = ceil(A(:,c));
```